# Swift 2.0: Initialize a CBCharacteristic?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, swift2

I am making an app using the CoreBluetooth framework and I recently ported it to swift 2.0. In my code I have a global variable that is a CBCharacteristic, and in swift 1.2 I could just do:

```
var bob:CBCharacteristic = CBCharacteristic()
```

But now it gives me the error that the init() function for CBCharacteristic has been explicitly hidden, so I can't initialize it. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: What's the purpose of that variable in your code? Would switching to `CBMutableCharacteristic` solve your issue?

Comment: @hennes I set the variable once I discover the device I want to connect to so that I can read data from it. Also, `CBMutableCharacteristic` is not initializable in swift 2 either.

Comment: Looks like CBMutableCharacteristic has `init(type UUID: CBUUID?, properties: CBCharacteristicProperties, value: NSData?, permissions: CBAttributePermissions)`?

Comment: Don't think you need the type speficier on your var.

Comment: @nielsbot it *has* it, but when I look at the error it gives me in xcode, it says: `init() has been explicitly marked unavailable here (CoreBluetooth.CBMutableCharacteristic)` and the same for CBCharacteristic.

Comment: wonder why? are these returned from some API somewhere? could be an API bug. a workaround is to create a factory method in obj-c and call that from Swift instead.

Comment: @nielsbot Okay, thanks! That worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instances of `CBCharacteristic` can only be retrieved through the service discovery process.

In your Swift 1.2 code you were assigning an 'empty' `CBCharacteristic` just to satisfy the compiler regarding uninitialised variables, but you would have had a run-time issue had you tried to use `bob` before assigning the 'real' `CBCharacteristic`.

Swift is designed to make it easier to produce "safe" code that doesn't have subtle run-time issues from the incorrect use of types. It makes no sense to instantiate an instance of `CBCharacteristic` directly and in Swift 2.0 you are actively prevented from doing so.

If your `CBCharacteristic` is a property then it should be declared as an optional since it may not have a value until the characteristic is discovered

```
var bob:CBCharacteristic?
```

or, if you are sure your code won't attempt to access `bob` before it is set -

```
var bob:CBCharacteristic!
```

The first will ensure that you write code to unwrap the optional before you use it and the second will give a run-time error if you use it before it is set - both of these are preferable to the potentially difficult to debug problem you would have had simply referencing an 'empty' `CBCharacteristic`

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes total sense.

Comment: What a beautiful and useful explanation (applicable well beyond just this example). Thank you so much for taking your time to explain it so well!